# How to preserve original numbering from a numbered list?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a document (a set of practice problems) that looks like this:

---

> 1 This is my first problem
>
> Problem statement
>
> Expected results
>
> Hint
>
> Answer
>
> Discussion
>
> 2 This is my second problem
>
> Problem statement
>
> Expected results
>
> Hint
>
> Answer
>
> Discussion

---

All of these sections have a bunch of text in them. They also have lots of formatting applied to them.

I was told by reviewers that it's too easy just to look ahead from the problem to the answer, without trying hard to solve it.

So, I'd like to completely split out the problem and the answer section. Of course, the numbers need to be the same (the numbering for problem 1 needs to match the numbering for answer 1).

I'm trying to split the document into 2 sections, one with problem statement, hint, and expected results, and the other with answer and discussion.

The Answer and Discussion section should preserve the numbering of the original problem. The finished split document should look like this:

---

> PROBLEM SECTION
>
> 1 This is my first problem
>
> Problem statement
>
> Expected results
>
> Hint
>
> 2 This is my second problem
>
> Problem statement
>
> Expected results
>
> Hint
>
> ANSWER SECTION
>
> 1 This is my first problem
>
> Answer
>
> Discussion
>
> 2 This is my second problem
>
> Answer
>
> Discussion

---

I thought it would be very easy, I could just copy the whole thing, then in the original section I would delete the answer and discussion, and in the new section (answers) I would delete the problem statement, expected results, and hint.

However, I'm having a hard time keeping the SAME NUMBERING - so that problems and answers can be linked via the number.

I looked at this page - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6#bm3. But it looks like unless I'm okay losing all my formatting (just pasting raw text), it won't work.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question correctly, you basically need to have two separate numbered lists, one for your questions and the other for your answers.

To help organise the formatting of your numbered lists you can use a combination of two approaches:

1. Selectively choosing between adding a new paragraph or adding a new line
2. Using page and/or section breaks

**New paragraph v new line**

When you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in Microsoft Word, a new line is inserted into the document. However, there is a difference between pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> actually creates a new paragraph, while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> gets Word to just go down a line.

In summary, by using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> you remove the gap between each line. This approach is also very useful when working with a bulleted or numbered list, because pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> allows you to go to the next line without creating a new bullet or number. You can then add text and use whatever formatting you need. It may take you a little while to get used to this and what you can do, but it's well worth it.

Regardless of what you do with numbered lists, it's also handy to get familiar with the various numbering options by **right-clicking** on the actual numbers in your numbered list. Below is a screenshot of the options I mean:

[image]

Have a play with these options to help you format your sections as you need.

**Using page and/or section breaks**

I feel you can achieve what you want with the above info, but another option that may help with your overall document layout is to use page breaks and/or section breaks.

You may be aware you can insert page breaks from the Insert tab in the ribbon, but you can also access a full set of options in the Page Layout tab.

More specifically, go to the Page Layout tab and look within the Page Setup group to find the Breaks icon. Clicking on this provides a number of options (see screenshot below):

[image]

So, you may want to use separate sections to manage how you separate your Problems and Answers.

Comment: I've added some clarification to the question. Does it help? Basically, problems/answers were in the same section, and I want to have the answers in a separate section. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated my answer. This should help you achieve what you wnat.